# Macintosh White screen after login

Tags: macos, terminal

Please note that it is my first time using MAC.
I have a mac pro that is showing white screen after login.
On the login screen a warning message that the disk is full is shown.
I am trying to free space using the terminal ( such as deleting junk files), but I do not know how.
I have searched for the terminal commands, and for the junk files path, but could not find anything helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `rm` command. It will delete the file or folder of choice

```
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

example:

```
rm /Users/account/Desktop/myfolder
```

Comment: how can i list the folders/files in the directory so I can know what to delete

Comment: @HasanShouman Just start typing the path and then press tab button, it will list all the available file or folders that have the word you are typing or are most similar.